# Error linking IBM Bluemix Devops id to IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, user-accounts

I get the following error when linking IBM id to Bluemix:

```
IBM Bluemix

Failure during registration

An error occurred.

Try again in a few minutes. If you continue to have problems, click the following link to get help: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/
```

This is after following the email I received:

```
Hello there.
Your account requires attention
The authentication process for IBM Bluemix DevOps Services is integrating with IBM Bluemix. To ensure that you can continue to log in without disruption, register with Bluemix by taking a few steps.
SIGN UP
Step 1
Click SIGN UP
Step 2
Click Already have an IBM ID?
Step 3
Type your phone number and email address.
Step 4
Check your email to verify that you're registered. In the email, click Validate Email Address.
Step 5
Sign in by typing your IBM ID and password.
Step 6
Welcome to IBM Bluemix. You're done!
```

I have tried this a few times, and I'm not sure what I need to do next.

Comment: Is the first error message coming up from the Bluemix Dashboard login?

Comment: I don't think so.  The url is https://console.ng.bluemix.net/registration/?utm_medium=bluemix_v1_signup&utm_source=silverpop&utm_campaign=IDS_GH and the error occurs when I click the button on step 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please address the problem to Bluemix support using the following mail: id@bluemix.net. This team will assist you on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Bluemix support confirmed my ID was linked and asked me to use the regular login from here on out.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. But I realized that I already have registered in Bluemix.
So, right under "Already have an IBM ID?" there is: "Already signed up for Bluemix? Log in".

This "Log in" link points to login page which, after entering my credentials, it redirects to https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?direct=classic. I don't know what this argument "?direct=classic" means, but the page won't show. So I removed it and everything is working fine.